# Unbound Classopath Container

Tags: java, eclipse

Ive just downloaded and installed JDK21 and Eclips,when I Start to write a code I get an error ,;Unbound Classpath Container,JRE system Library,Ive started new sop Ive new with all that and have no clue whats going wrong.I have windows 10(64 bit),.dop I need to install sth more ?or what Im doing wrong?

Ive tried to reinstall again and also JDK17 but  system tell me,.its not comopatible with the newest release of Eclips

Comment: Configure the Java installations you want to use in your projects in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: Also, it is recommended that you download and use the Eclipse **Installer** for your platform.  This **includes** the JRE that is used to run Eclipse.  (For the record, with Eclipse 2023‑09, that is Java 17, not Java 21.)

Comment: Finally, if you want to target Java 21, that is (apparently) not supported by Eclipse 2023-09 directly.  Instead you can install Java 21 support via a Marketplace plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-21-support-eclipse-2023-09-429.  I imagine that the next Eclipse release will support Java 21 directly.